# how to redirect to the home page after login angular

Tags: angular

I don't know why my navbar is shown also on my login page. The second is when I login, I get the token and I can save in my `localstorage` but still, it does not redirect me to the first page, now I'm going to write what I have done, here is my *module.ts*.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([                       
   {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
   {path:'app-events',component:EventsComponent},
   {path:'app-turbine-comparison',component:TurbineComparisonComponent}
])
```

and here is my login function:

```
signIn(credntials){
  this.authaervice.login(credntials)
  .subscribe(result=>{  
    if(result){
      localStorage.setItem('token',result.toString()); 
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
    else
      this.invalidLogin=true;
   })
}
```

my app.html:

```
   <nav>my nabvar stuff</nav>
 
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My navbar is before router-outlet

Comment: Please elaborate more on what is happening and what you need to do, also share your app.component.html if possibe

Comment: I'd discourage storing the token in localStorage. Any script you include on your webpage can read the localStorage for your website. Try to use cookie auth instead for your website.

Comment: @Pieterjan sorry i did not get your point whats the problem with localstorage

Comment: Each script you include on your webpage can read localStorage for your website. So if you'd use the Youtube `iframe_api.js` on your website, this script is able to read the localStorage for your website for the visitor. Making it possible to steal the JWT, perhaps AJAX it to a server in Russia, and perform requests on the visitors behalf. Now on the other hand, with cookie authentication, the script doesn't even need to retrieve any information to make authenticated requests, but it still is more secure than simply storing a JWT in localstorage. Continued...

Comment: So the best approach is to use a combination of Cookie auth (the proven authentication mechanism for web applications) and the use of a short-lived CSRF token to mitigate against CSRF attacks. I already read the [following angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection) that covers the angular side of CSRF protection, but I'm still looking into this stuff myself.

Answer (score 1):

What's your home page? You have no home page in your router and yet you navigate on '/' on successful sign on, which redirects you again to login page defined here :

```
{path:'',component:LoginComponent},
```

Your navbar shows on your login page because it's outside of your router outlet so it will show on every page.
In your app component, you could simply read the token from the localstorage and only render the nav component if there is a valid token :

```
<nav *ngIf="token">my nabvar stuff</nav>
 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in your app.component.ts ->

```
token: string;

ngOnInit(){
    this.token = this.readToken();
}

readToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```